# Como mudar a cor da barra de rolagem por JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quero mudar a cor da barra de rolagem apenas quando o usuário rolar a tela. Tentei o código abaixo mas não funcionou. Como faço?

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body::-webkit-scrollbar").css("background-color", "#333");
        console.log('fsdfs');
    },500);
});
```

Comment: Você não pode manipular pseudo-elementos `::-webkit-scrollbar` usando o jquery

Comment: Utilize uma classe no CSS `.body.customScroll` e com o *jQuery* você utiliza `$("body").addClass("customScroll")`

Comment: Felipe, se a resposta resolveu o problema, é importante marcar ✔️. Leia a página [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como é o sistema do site. ObG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JavaScript não consegue alterar pseudo-elementos, mas você pode criar uma classe no CSS e adicionar ao `body` ao fazer scroll:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $("body").addClass("scroller");
});
```

```css
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 17px; /* largura do scroll */
}
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
   background: #eee; /* cor do fundo */
}
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: blue;  /* cor do scroll */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role a tela
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```